# How to create different objects with a constructor list

Tags: python, list, class, constructor

I have a list which has different constructors of different classes. But the constructors always return the same object because they have the same memory direction.

I have something like this:

```
l=[class1(),class2(),class3()]
l2 = []
```

If I try to create different objects with it, it returns the same object with the same memory direction. I'm doing this:

```
for i in range(50):
    obj = l[random]
    l2.append(obj)
```

l2 has 50 objects but all the objects of the first class are the same and they have the same memory direction. Same happens with the other classes.

I would like to have 50 differents objects.

Comment: 1) *"I have a list which has differents constructors of differents classes."* No, you have a list that contains 3 different *objects*. Not constructors. 2) *"But the constructors always return me the same object because they have the same memory direction."* What? Are you saying that `l[0] is l[1] is l[2]`?

Comment: `l=[class1(),class2(),class3()]` *creates three objects*.  It is not, in any sense, a "list of constructors".  Appending one of those three objects to a list is not going to magically cause a new object to be constructed.

Comment: True, how could I call the differents constructors randomly and create diferents objects each time? Thanks for the anwsers.

Answer (score 0):

You  must call the constructor of the class each time you want to add an instance to the list.  For this I would suggest that you use a list of classes rather than a list of object instances (otherwise you're just adding the same references to these 3 instances to the list)

```
l=[class1,class2,class3]
for _ in range(50):
    cls = l[random]
    l2.append(cls())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is what I was looking for.